# Can't get GNATbench working with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ada

I'm trying to get the GNATbench plugin to work with Eclipse. I put the plugin and feature files in the correct places. I restart Eclipse and I am now given the option to create a new Ada project but when I try to do it I get this error:

> **The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in com.adacore.gnatbench.cdt was unable to load class
>   com.adacore.gnatbench.ui.internal.wizards.NewAdaProject. An error
>   occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   com.adacore.gnatbench.ui (235).**

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I would say at least com.adacore.gnatbench.ui plugin (jar...) is missing, could you please check your dropins or plugins folder in your eclipse directory to see if it is there or not.

Comment: or you can start your eclipse from console like this: ./eclipse -clean, this might help.

Comment: The com.adacore.gnatbench.ui plugin is there and -clean didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the README file of this plugin, it says this is required:

"C/C++ Development Tools (CDT) plug-in for Eclipse 3.5.x or 3.6.x"

Have you installed that?

The other important thing is that the downloaded archive file is actually a P2 repository installable file. In this case I would unzip a new eclipse (or remove manually the related plugins you copied over, this is the hard way), start it, click on help/install new software, click add, select archive, point to your downloaded GNATbench zip file, select the 2 features appearing on the avail "software" list and continue the wizard normally (next, finish...). If there is a version problem the wizard should "validate" it.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and I can start a C or a C++ project just fine. I also went to Help->About Eclipse->Install New Software and installed the archive that way. Still getting the same error.

Comment: is there any error related to this plugin in your Eclipse error log?

Comment: I checked it and there is an exception during the creation of the Ada project, I don't have the eclipse plugin source code, but I guess form an end-user perspective there is nothing to do right now for you. If they have a forum post the exception there.

Comment: Hmm, well that sucks. Are there any other good Ada IDE plugins for Eclipse?

Comment: I am not really familiar with Ada so I don't know, however this is a commercial software you wanted to install, I would not give up on that. Since this seems to be a pretty cruicial bug they might solve it soon.

Answer (score 5):

This is the issue you'll see if you attempt to use GNATbench with the 64-bit version of Eclipse. As the system requirements note in the readme, it's only compatible with the 32-bit version. I just did a quick test, which confirmed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was a plugin for Ada called Hibachi, IIRC... I'm not sure where it stands on development or completeness though.